# How does Qubes do memory management, especially with regard to shared objects?

Tags: dynamic-linking, shared-library, resources, qubes, memory-management

I'm just reading about [Qubes OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubes_OS), and I have a very simple question -- how does it do memory management and shared object use?

Feel free to correct any misconceptions or errs in vocab, but we have the ability to pull in a shared object into two running executables ([`dlopen(3)`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html)). The shared object exists only in memory once. Programs that use that shared object are dynamically linked to the same copy of the in-memory library (`-fPIC`).

Qubes bills itself as *security through isolation.* At the same time the [Qubes FAQ](https://www.qubes-os.org/faq/) which doesn't addresses this makes mention of *"smart use of Xen shared memory."*

So how does Qubes handle shared in-memory resources?

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding what is meant by shared memory in this context. Xen shared memory refers to sharing a range of memory between different virtual machines, which is used by Qubes for passing information between VMs.
Memory resources used by a VM exist separately in that, and are not shared with any other virtual machine. As such, **every shared object will only be shared within a virtual machine**, and using it within a second virtual machine will create a second copy.